# Map URL "/users/id" to "/dashboard" in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I map the url /users/:id to /dashboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the `id` parameter with URL `/dashboard`? Or is this about the "current" user?

If these pages are about different users, one from parameter, the other from session. Then you actually need different controllers for these 2 URLs.

Here is how I would do it:

**routes.rb**

```
match "dashboard" => 'users#show', :defaults => { :id => -1 }
```

**UsersController.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id] == -1 ? current_user_id : params[:id])
  ...
```

I let you do the implementation of `current_user_id` :-)

Comment: It is about the current_user. When I login, I want the URL to show /dashboard instead of /users/:id like it shows now.

Comment: @donald: do you mean the login page should be served from `/dashboard`, or that the user should be redirected to `/dashboard` after logging in?

Comment: @zetetic should be redirected to /dashboard once logged in.

Comment: could you please explain better how that works? Shall I put that @user in all the methods in the controller? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
match "users/:id" => "YourDashboardController#dashboard"
```

Comment: @donald: edited, you need to specify the controller in which the dashboard action exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
match "users/:id" => "YourDashboardController#dashboard"

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like that:

```
match "/dashboard", :to => "users#show", :as => "dashboard"
```

and after login redirect to dashboard_path