# rails 3 - user dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dashboard

I'm looking at creating a dashboard for a logged in user which would then query the display other models data.

Would the best way to do this be to use something similar to this post: [Map URL "/users/id" to "/dashboard" in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291922/map-url-users-id-to-dashboard-in-rails-3), then to use a custom dashboard controller or would something like the Cells gem make this more straight forward?

I've also read this post which talks about something similar: [How to pass argument to delegate method in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537180/how-to-pass-argument-to-delegate-method-in-rails)

Many thanks,

James

Comment: Kind of depends what you want to do. If it makes sense for the /users/1 show action to be the dashboard, then you could simply use that action, and add another url for /dashboard. However, if you want more than just links to other controllers & actions, such as customizing the dashboard, i suggest making a dashboard controller.

Comment: Good point. It might be worth creating a seperate controller otherwise things could get messy. Could I just use a standard controller used with the generate command?

Comment: Yes, that's a good place to start. You can always add a model later if you need to store settings or something.

Answer (score 2):

I've decided to use the Cells gem (http://cells.rubyforge.org/) along with a dashboard controller. Something similar is discussed here: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/04/11/cells-partial-controllers-and-views-for-rails-3/

Some of these views will need to be used across several pages so this solution should keep things neat and maintainable.

Comment: Almost 3 years later , i am still facing the same issue . Any light on how to go on doing it ? . Rails version used is 3.2.8